# Memory leak when sliding Custome UITableViewCell/ Custom UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm running my app on my iPhone 4S, I am using custom table view controller and custom table view cell, when i slide the tableview up into whitespace and likewise down into whitespace i get a memory leak, see picture attached
[image]

I can't seem to pinpoint where the problem is, or even if its the cell causing the problem.

I have a SeasonTableViewController,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SeasonTableViewCell";

//SeasonTableViewCell *cell = (SeasonTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
SeasonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%@",[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]);
if(cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"STableView" owner:self options:nil];

    //cell = [[[SeasonTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    cell = (SeasonTableViewCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

Season *season = [seasonTableArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

cell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[season season_title]];

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


return cell;
}
```

This is the output from the NSLog on NSLog@"%@",[tableview dequeResuableCellWithIdentifier:.....];

```
2012-05-31 11:26:10.799 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:10.804 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:10.809 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:10.813 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:10.817 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:11.185 myTVApp[1462:707] <SeasonTableViewCell: 0xfe24da0; baseClass =       UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xfe24860>>
2012-05-31 11:26:11.187 myTVApp[1462:707] <SeasonTableViewCell: 0xfe25730; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 132; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xfe244a0>>
2012-05-31 11:26:11.189 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:11.191 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
2012-05-31 11:26:11.194 myTVApp[1462:707] (null)
```

In the above.. I have 5 custom SeasonTableViewCells showing in myTableView, the rest are just the normal white cells with nothing in them,

Below is SeasonTableViewCell,

```
#import "SeasonTableViewCell.h"

@implementation SeasonTableViewCell
@synthesize label1;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}  

-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
[label1 release];
//[label2 release];
}
```

Any help of indication is appreciated and thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest iOS. See [this thread on the developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/630695#630695) (Near the bottom of the thread, an Apple employee explains).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I seriously thought it was on my end